# How to alter stored procedure in a MySQL database using the Linux command prompt?

Tags: linux, command-line, mysql

I want to alter the stored procedure in my server machine. I'm uploading the codes via SSH Linux command prompt, I need to alter an existing stored procedure in my server. I don't have c-panel or phpMyAdmin access. I have to update it via a command prompt.

#### stored procedure

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `dbname`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_data`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_data`(
    f_id INT(11), 
    f_guild_parent_id INT(11),OUT lastid INT
    )
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO tablename
         (
         id,
         character_detail_id,
         media_id,
         )
         VALUES 
         ( 
         f_id,
         f_character_detail_id,
         f_media_id,
         NOW() ,
         NOW() 
          );
          SET lastid = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I need the command to perform this. Can any one give me the command with an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have console access to your database you can load this file via the command line like this:

```
$ mysql < /path/to/text_file.sql
```

Where `text_file` is the name of the above file. If you're already at the `mysql>` prompt you can `source` the `text_file` using either of these methods too:

```
mysql> source /path/to/text_file.sql

-or-

mysql> \. /path/to/text_file.sql
```

You might need to pass a username + password to `mysql` to "connect" to the database. This can be done like so:

```
$ mysql -u <user> -p < /path/to/txt_file.sql
```

You'll be prompted for the password when you run the above command, after providing it, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and your `.sql` command file should execute.

#### References

- [4.5.1.5. Executing SQL Statements from a Text File](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-batch-commands.html)
- [3.5. Using mysql in Batch Mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-mode.html)

Comment: I tried this command mysql> source /path/to/text_file.sql,in command prompt it is saying Databases changed "0 rows affected" and stored procedure not affected.

Comment: @user2086641 - You'll want to list them and confirm they're there first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733349/list-of-stored-procedures-functions-mysql-command-line

Comment: It worked good.